# basic HTTP Client from scratch

Tags: java, http

So my assignment is as the title indicated. Take a url, get the hostname and pathname from it and then open a socket and write to/read from it.
I've split the url and tried making a socket as such:

```
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        outStream.writeChars(pathname);
        outStream.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Then I've tried a number of ways to get the response, for example I used:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt")));  
byte[] buf = new byte[256];  
int n = 0;  
while ((n=in.read(buf))>=0) {  
    out.write(buf, 0, n); 
}
out.flush();  
out.close();
```

As well as a number of other variations but they always seem to get stuck at the while loop. I'm supposed to read the response as bytes and then convert the array of bytes into a string. Why is this getting stuck on the while loop?

Comment: you need to learn HTTP protocol. first point, you need to send request first, then you can open input stream. as a basic point, try to send "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n\r\n", as a simple example, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I think, before going to HTTP protocol, you need to get it to work, at least, exchange the info, how are you initiating socket that is listening?

Comment: This may be what you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: it's actually based off the school website that the professor made so we can actually test this. For example, hostname would be something alone the lines of "google.ca" and the pathname would be "/imghp"
So I would be requesting "google.ca/imghp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to sent correct data in regard of HTTP protocol. try this

```
    try {
        String hostname = "stackoverflow.com";
        String requestHeaders[][] = {
            { "Host" , hostname } ,
            { "User-Agent" , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" } ,

        };
        String pathname = "questions/33047629/basic-http-client-from-scratch/33047769#33047769";
        int port = 80;
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String data = "GET /"+pathname+" HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        for (int i=0;i<requestHeaders.length;i++){
            data += requestHeaders[0]+": "+requestHeaders[1]+"\r\n";
        }
        data += "\r\n";
        outStream.writeChars(data.getBytes());
        outStream.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

there are some browsers plugins that shows which header are sent by your browser. you can learn them from plugin and implement them as I implemented for 2 headers

Comment: It worked for the most part but at the same time, the response I receive gives me a 400 (Bad Request) Error saying "<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />"

Comment: so, you need to complete request headers. I think "User-Agent" , "Accept" or some other headers are missing that target web site have to have to continue process. check my codes how you can add headers to request

Comment: oh god, I found the problem
my pathname started with a "/"
and so using "GET /"+pathname
was giving it essentially //pathname.  
thanks for all your help

Answer (score -1):

I think your condition is wrong, should be >0 and not >=0

Comment: well I'm essentially checking that ((n = in.read(buf)) != -1)

Comment: Is it possible to get a negative -1? Sorry I'm a newbie, as per your comment it does not seem so, as your never exiting the loop

Comment: ok, after doing quick search I see examples that check if >0 only, did you try changing your condition? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedinputstream_read.htm